# Retrieving data from firebase node in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble getting from my Firebase database data to an android app and the Firebase listener and data snapshot documentations aren't really helping.

Say I have a database with the nodes structured as below:

```
Contacts-->
       John : 1334255
       May :  3345777
       James : 5799862
       Ford : 4574878
```

How can I directly retrieve the contacts from the nodes with the key and value both as strings , without having to cast them into some object(that's not the string object).

I want to be able to display the names(keys) as contact names and the numbers(their values) as Contact number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
DatabaseReference contactsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contacts");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.getKey();
            String contactNumber = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name + ": " + contactNumber);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
contactsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks alot, this worked and I didnt even have to use the for loop

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr write them as something other than numbers**

The values in your example are `Long` (integers). Assuming they're phone numbers, you'll probably want to store them as strings anyway. When you write a value to Firebase, it will infer the type and [store it as one of the following](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write):

- `String` (will appear in quotes)
- `Long` (whole number)
- `Double` (decimal number)
- `Boolean` (`true` or `false` without quotes)
- `Map<String, Object>` (key with children)
- `List<Object>` (key with children)

In your case, since you want to treat it as a `String` type when it's being read, just write it as a string:

If you're setting the values from **client code**, use the `String` type when you create the value.

If you're manually entering them from the **dashboard**, you can either wrap them in quotes or use non-numeric characters like the familiar format `(123) 456-7890`. Any value you type in that doesn't evaluate to a `Long`/`Double`/`Boolean` will be interpreted as a String.